# Can't install d3heatmap in R

Tags: r, d3heatmap

I am trying to install d3heatmap by both install.packages and devtools: install_github. I wouldn't succeed in either.

```
install.packages('d3heatmap')
```

> Warning in install.packages :   InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The host name
>   in the certificate is invalid or does not match'

Warning in install.packages :

OR in devtool:

```
devtools::install_github("rstudio/d3heatmap")
```

> Downloading GitHub repo rstudio/d3heatmap@master Installing d3heatmap
>   Skipping 5 packages not available: base64enc, dendextend, htmlwidgets,
>   png, scales "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file
>   --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \   "C:/Users/yli/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpy8LkKm/devtools24e41b2d6e47/rstudio-d3heatmap-57d9756"
>   --library="C:/Program  \   Files/R/R-3.2.3/library" --install-tests
>
> ERROR: dependencies 'htmlwidgets', 'png', 'base64enc', 'dendextend'
>   are not available for package 'd3heatmap'
>   * removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/library/d3heatmap' Error: Command failed (1)

Anyone knows how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: to solve the dependencies issue, add `dependencies=TRUE` to the call to `install_github()`. Choose a different mirror for the certificate issue.

Comment: I tried to add the dependencies, still got an error. Do i have to add those packages manually?

Comment: Did you change the mirror? I've not had severe issues with release R, only R-devel (which requires compilation for everything).

Comment: can you include your sessionInfo()

Comment: This is my session info:
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3